# Bootgrid pagination and search not working

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am trying to get data from json using [bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/), the data can be display to grid, but its pagination and search are not working.  I tried to debug, but no error was displayed.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#grid-command-buttons").bootgrid(
    {
            ajax: true,
            url: "/newspider/test.do",
            post: function (data)
            {
            },
        });
})
```

Here is my servlet

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); // 设置编码  
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");  
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    SqlSession sqlSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    UserMapper userMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("current", 1);
    jsonObject.put("rowCount", 10);
    JSONArray rows = new JSONArray();       
    List<ResumeShow> si = userMapper.selectRShow();
    int cont=si.size();
    int cnt=1;      
    for (ResumeShow resumeShow : si) {
        JSONObject cell = new JSONObject();
        cell.put("id", cnt++);
        cell.put("seeker_name", resumeShow.getSeeker_name());
        cell.put("sex", resumeShow.getSex());
        cell.put("age", resumeShow.getAge());
        cell.put("residence", resumeShow.getResidence());
        cell.put("education", resumeShow.getEducation());
        cell.put("profession", resumeShow.getProfession());
        cell.put("school", resumeShow.getSchool());
        cell.put("expect_salary", resumeShow.getExpect_salary());
        cell.put("work_place", resumeShow.getWork_place());
        cell.put("last_company", resumeShow.getLast_company());
        cell.put("position_name", resumeShow.getPosition_name());
        cell.put("last_period", resumeShow.getLast_period());
        cell.put("workYears", resumeShow.getWorkYears());
        cell.put("household_registration", resumeShow.getHousehold_registration());
        cell.put("job_category", resumeShow.getJob_category());
        rows.add(cell);
    }
    jsonObject.put("rows", rows);
    jsonObject.put("total", cont);
    out.print(jsonObject);
}
```

Does anybody know what's up ?thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need a little more information to help you, such as the associated html and possibly more of the servlet code.  It would also be helpful if you could be a bit more clear on if you are currently getting -any- data displayed.

Comment: Here is my HTML table                                                                         <table id="grid-command-buttons" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped " align="center">`   and tr like <th data-column-id="seeker_name">姓名</th>

Comment: You should edit your original question and add the full html there.